# retrieve text in my mySql database and put into texbox using ODBC in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, odbc

I want to retrieve a question from my db and put it into textbox for security questions but I don't know how. I am using ODBC as connection in vb.net into mysql.
Here is my code

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Public Class forgPass

Dim con As New OdbcConnection("DSN=nohdb")
Dim com As New OdbcCommand
Dim dt As DataTable

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    con.Open()
    com = New OdbcCommand("SELECT question1 FROM sec_questions WHERE='admin'", con)
    dt = New DataTable
    dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)
    ques1.Text = dt.ReadXml
    con.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: "i dont know how." is a really vague question so you need to improve it so we understand what your issue is. But as for the sql part I see that your syntax for the WHERE clause is wrong, it should be `WHERE someColumn = 'admin'` where someColumn needs to be replaced with the name of the correct column.

Comment: i want to get the text in the db in put it into textbox in my windows form any idea?

Comment: No, I helped with the sql part but that's all since I don't know VB (any more). And improve your question by editing it instead of posting comments.

Comment: Can you explain what your data looks like. What columns do you have? Is the data in XML (you have a strange ReadXml call)?

Comment: Why are you using ODBC? MySql has a native provider.

Comment: DataTable.ReadXML requires a parameter. Why did you choose to try and fill a text box that way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

I am assuming the following

1. You can insert the correct connection string in the `con` constructor. See
   https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/
   for reference.
2. `question1` is the name of a field in your database table.
3. `sec_questions` is the name of a table in your database.
4. Replace `SomeFieldName` with the name of field where `admin` is
   found.

Keep your database objects local so you can control that they are closed and disposed. A single `Using...End Using` block handles this for you even if there is an error.

The user interface is not updated until the database objects are closed and disposed with the `End Using`.

To retrieve data from the DataTable you can refer to the first row in the Rows collection which is index 0. Then the column name, `question1`. Since the datatype is unknown until runtime we call `.ToString` to satisfy `Option Strict`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            com As New MySqlCommand("SELECT question1 FROM sec_questions WHERE SomeFieldName ='admin';", con)
        con.Open()
        dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    ques1.Text = dt.Rows(0)("question1").ToString
End Sub
```